# How can I use Kafka to retain logs in logstash for longer period?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, apache-kafka, kibana, logstash-configuration

Currently I use redis -> s3 -> elastic search -> kibana stack to pipe and visualise my logs. But due to large volume of data in elastic search I can retain logs upto 7 days.

I want to bring kafka cluster in this stack and retain logs for more number of days. I am thinking of following stack.

app nodes piping logs to kafka -> kafka cluster -> elastics search cluster -> kibana

How can I use kafka to retain logs for more number of days?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the Apache Kafka [broker configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs), there are two properties that determine when a log will get deleted. One by time and the other by space.

```
log.retention.{ms,minutes,hours}
log.retention.bytes
```

> Also note that if both log.retention.hours and log.retention.bytes are both set we delete a segment when either limit is exceeded.

Those two dictate when logs are deleted in Kafka. The log.retention.bytes defaults to -1, and I'm pretty sure leaving it to -1 allows only the time config to solely determine when a log gets deleted.

So to directly answer your question, set log.retention.hours to however many hours you wish to retain your data and don't change the log.retention.bytes configuration.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I feed logs from my application node catalina.out to kafka clutser in logstash?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used logstash. You originally just asked how Kafka can be configured to retain logs, so I answered that. It would probably be better if you asked a totally new question which pertained to your logstash setup.