# How can I push logs from tomcat servers to Kafka cluster?

Tags: logstash, apache-kafka, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Currently I use redis -> s3 -> elastic search -> kibana stack to pipe and visualize my logs.
I want to bring kafka cluster in this stack and push data from app nodes to kafka cluster.

How exactly can I do this?

Comment: That's a pretty vague question and to me seems primarily opinion based. What have you tried, experimented with, or read about it? One thing I would note, is when you ask questions and people answer them, you should probably accept, upvote, or leave feedback on the answer. It's a good way to give back to people who spend time helping you with a problem. (I was the person that answered the question, so hopefully that doesn't come off as too biased, sorry if it does)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565895/how-can-i-use-kafka-to-retain-logs-in-logstash-for-longer-period

Comment: I would love to upvote your answer.But Stackoverflow should let me do it :)

Comment: I forget they cap that at 15 rep. Just letting you know, it took me like 5 questions before I learned how to accept an answer.